# my computer becomes freezes after entering password

Tags: 14.04

sir
I have installed ubuntu 14.04 today. when I rebooted aftet installation, it asked to enter password. But the twist is that, after pressing enter key the computer becomes freezes. sometimes the mouse pointer may move for seconds. no toolbar or anything  .
    I am using dual booting with windows. pls rply. expect a soluton

Comment: boot into recovery and see any logs in `/var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, it is difficult to know, but it sounds like it could be an xserver problem.

Try booting up again, then when the grub menu shows, press the option to edit (I think this is 'e', but not certain, but you will see it in the menu) then when on the edit screen, find the line that contains **vmlinuz** (usually ending in **quiet splash**), and add the word **nomodeset** to the end of it.  Then return to the boot menu and continue booting.

Note that if you are not dual booting, the menu may not show - so after the bios information shows on boot-up, press the **shift** key and this should show it.