# problem of freezing after entering password

Tags: 14.04

sir,
As u said I tried and edited in the command box while booting.I entered nomodeset to the line contains vmlinuz.It is worked but I need to enter this command everytime I am booting up... can't save using F10.What's the solution?

Whie I use the code,no problem with the computer. But the problem rises again when I tries to reboot.

Comment: Sorry but are you trying to reach someone? if so use @(Username); If not please edit the post to better explain the issue

Comment: This is their prior post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/683495/my-computer-becomes-freezes-after-entering-password I assume it is a language barrier.